# SSRS 2008 R2 drill through report promts for authentication

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, drillthrough

I am facing an issue with running a drill through report from the parent report. When I click on the link field in the parent report to drill through report I am getting prompted for username and password (windows security).

I am connecting to the drill via go to URL and passing a parameter through it.
Is there any way I can get rid off this authentication while connecting to the drill through report?
I want to get rid off this authentication cause we have users connecting from outside network (internet) and there is a first level of authentication on the parent report through a .net website (ReportViewer).

I tried storing dataset credentials in the reportserver but that didn't stop the authentication prompt.

Go to URL:

`https://mywebsite.com/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fOrders+Drill+Through+Report&rs:command=Render&rc:Parameters=false&OrderNumber=1234`

I also tried removing keeping only RSWindowsNTLM authentication type in rsreportserver.config file. But that didn't help.

Comment: I can't offer an answer because network auth is somewhat beyond me, but I can say that most likely the authentication prompt isn't coming from SSRS it's coming from IIS. Which means you need to look at IIS config.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Did you find any solution to this by now?

Answer (score 0):

**Just go to your Dataset properties and change the credentials setting there.**

> Create a Domain account with minimum permissions (enough to execute
>   the report). Add it to your reports server.
>
> Go to Dataset Properties. -->
>
> Go to credentials Tab select `use this username and password` and
>   Provide details of that account in there. -->
>
> Redeploy the datasource -->
>
> next time when any user executes the report these provided credentials
>   will be used for reports Authentication.
>
> You can also select the Second option `Do not Use credentials` but its
>   a very unsecure option.

[image]

Comment: I tried that but it didn't help. I think what @JC. said above is correct. The authentication on drill down report is coming from IIS. I need to figure out how to disable authentication from IIS. Any idea on that? I tried enabling Anonymous authentication and disabling windows authentication but it still prompting me for username and password.